# Streaming string in a loop based on keywords in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have been trying to solve one problem to get keywords inside of a sentence in order.

XML example:

first.xml

```
<keyword>Today</keyword>
<keyword>Tomorrow</keyword>
```

second.xml

```
<keyword>Rainy</keyword>
<keyword>Sunny</keyword>
```

third.xml

```
<keyword>is</keyword>
<op>=</op>
<keyword>or</keyword>
<op>or</op>
<keyword>and</keyword>
<op>and</op>

<ex>Today is "Rainy" or "Cloudy" and Tomorrow is "Sunny"</ex>
```

I want to put these sentence in <`for-each>` loop. For instance:

- for each sentence, if for the first appearance, If $keywordFirst or $keywordSecond or $keywordThird exists, take the string value and cut the string there. Then, put the rest of the string in a loop and do the same operation until the end of sentence.

An example show could be.

First iteration:

Finding `Today`,

then put the sentence in a loop: is "Rainy" or "Cloudy" and Tomorrow is "Sunny"

find `is` and match it to '=' operator

then put the sentence in a loop:"Rainy" or "Cloudy" and Tomorrow is "Sunny"

find `"Rainy"`

then put the sentence in a loop:or "Cloudy" and Tomorrow is "Sunny"

find `or` and match to XSLT 2.0 multiple condition

etc..

Then I will combine them in a different way to create xPath definitions.

The output :

```
Today=('Rainy','Cloudy') and Tomorrow = 'Sunny'
```

How can I do it in XSLT 2.0 ? Thanks for suggestions

Comment: What should be your output look like ?

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen sorry to bother you a lot with this. but i am open to any suggestions or redriections. If the whole idea does not make sense to you, i am also eager to listen